# Is there an oscillating analog of the Gaussian distribution?

Tags: polynomials, special-functions

It frequently happens that, in some famillies of polynomials with positive coefficients, the coefficients of large polynomials look like a bell curve and tend to the distribution function of the Gaussian law. One obvious example is given by the familly $(1+x)^n$.

I know some examples of famillies of polynomials where the coefficients are not positive, but where plotting the coefficients give a nice oscillating curve, as the one displayed below.

[image: Plot of coefficients of some large polynomial]

My question is the following:

> Is there any known such oscillating function, with some kind of universal property ?

In other words, what is the function one can see in this picture ?

As far as I can tell, this does not seem to be given by a product of $\exp(-x^2)$ by trigonometric functions, because the local maxima do not fit very well on a parabola.

**EDIT:**

Here is a graph of the log of the absolute value of the coefficients, compared with a parabola.

[image: Comparison of log with parabola]

Comment: The convergence to a Gaussian that you describe is essentially due to the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), so you basically seem to be looking for a non-positive analog of a [stable distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution). What is that picture of yours a plot of, anyway?

Comment: The picture is the plot of the list of coefficients of one polynomial (in a familly of polynomials indexed by the integers). This is essentially a sequence of points, one with coordinates $(i,c_i)$ for each monomial $c_i x^i$.

Comment: Yes, I got that, I was just curious about what the specific family was.

Comment: The polynomials are numerators of $q$-Bernoulli polynomials (and variants of that).

Comment: Do you have a sense of the rate of decay of the function?

Comment: I have now added an image where one can compare the decay with the decay of a similar Gaussian.

Comment: Nice question. For the record, the scaling that transform the coefficients $(i,c_i)$ of $(1+x)^n$ into a standard normal PDF is given by $(x,y)\mapsto\left((2x-n)/\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}y/2^{n+1}\right)$.

Comment: Can you post a reference with more information about these "numerators of q-Bernoulli polynomials"? Google doesn't bring up much.

Comment: Oops, I should have said "numerators of $q$-Bernoulli numbers". These rational functions were introduced by Carlitz in  Carlitz, L. q-Bernoulli numbers and polynomials. Duke Math. J. 15, (1948). 987–1000. They are available in sage as follows: "from sage.combinat.q_bernoulli import q_bernoulli" then "q_bernoulli(20).numerator()"

Answer (score 5):

Another ... the Hermite functions.  Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$ times the density $\exp(-x^2)$.  Here is $H_{20}(x)\exp(-x^2)$

[image: herm]

Comment: This looks like a possible answer indeed. Sometimes I also see odd functions instead of even ones. They resemble to $H_{odd}(x) \exp(-x)$.

Comment: I am now more skeptical about this proposal, because in my examples, the oscillations are slower in the middle, whereas they are faster in the middle for $H_n(x)exp(-x^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $(1+x)^n$ itself does not have Gaussian coefficients 
when you go that far from the central term: by Stirling, 
for fixed $\rho \in (0,1)$ the $x^{\rho n}$ coefficient
$\bigl( {n \atop \rho n} \bigr)$
is roughly proportional to $\exp nH(\rho)$ where 
$H(\rho) = -\rho \log \rho - (1-\rho) \log(1-\rho)$.
Your graph looks like it could be something like this multiplied by $\cos cx$
for some $c \approx 1/6$.  The stationary-phase technique for finding the
asymptotic behavior of power-series coefficients often gives rise to
expressions such as this, though $H(r)$ might be a sum of more complicated
terms than just $-\rho \log \rho$ and $-(1-\rho) \log(1-\rho)$.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess [sinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_%28signal_processing%29).${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It seems to me that the function $sin(x)/x$ is not decreasing fast enough. Its graph does not look similar, and has long tails and many visible oscillations.

Answer (score 0):

A nice one is the [Dirichlet kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel).

Here is $D_5(x)$

[image: D5]

Comment: But that's just a finite approximation to sinc,
which we already know does not decay fast enough to match the
coefficients of the OP's polynomial (though it's certainly nice
for other applications).